# how to go back to saucy from trusty without losing data

Tags: 13.10, upgrade, 14.04

I have many problems with trusty and its hard to find solution to them because i don´t always find help here, so how can I go back to saucy without losing my data ?

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is take a backup and re install saucy and restore your previous backup.
And obviously, you have to take your backup on an external storage device.